# Click ouside form field does not close virtual keyboard in iPhone5

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a simple form in my website: touching each field, obviously open virtual keyboard in all mobile devices but I noted a different behaviour when clicking outside form fields, between Android devices and iPhone (I tried with 5s version).

If I do a click outside a field in an Android phone, virtual keyboard will close as expected. This is not true in iPhone. In this device, clicking outside form fields does not have any effect.

Please, can you confirm this behaviour? is there a way to have the same behaviour of Android phones, also on iPhones.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement this in your view controller's .m file ( where the the keyboard for example is being shown ) :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UIView * txt in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([txt isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && [txt isFirstResponder])
        {
            [txt resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually that's the code for native apps, not Web-based ones. Sorry !

Answer (score 0):

First add the following code to the viewcontroller of your nib file. For YourViewController.h add:

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;
```

For YouViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender {
[self.nameField resignFirstResponder];
[self.numberField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

nameField and numberField are the textfields you are using in your nib file.
Now select your nib file, Next, bring up the identity inspector and change the underlying class of your nib from UIView to UIControl.Next open connection inspector for your view.Drag from the Touch Down event to the File’s Owner icon, and choose the backgroundTap: action. 
Thats it. Run your code, now touching from any where outside the field i.e. background will close the keyboard.

Comment: I think he is not developing in Xcode and Objective-C ! He's developing his website ( with some web designing languages ) and wants touches on background to `resignFirstResponder` !

Comment: Exactly.... I did no think about XCODE, sorry....... I'm involved in my website so maybe.... a JQuery solution could be perfect if exist... thank you